# How can I skip a custom validation attribute when using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, automapper, custom-attributes

I'm mapping class Foo to class Bar with AutoMapper. Bar is a ViewModel of Foo. Bar has fewer properties, but all the properties it has matches the corresponding Foo properties exactly, except Bar has a custom validation attribute on one of the properties that isn't present in Foo.

```
public class Foo 
{
   string Prop1 { get; set; }
   string Prop2 { get; set; }
   string Prop3 { get; set; }
   string Prop4 { get; set; }
   string Prop5 { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   string Prop1 { get; set; }
   string Prop2 { get; set; }

   [CustomValidation]       
   string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use AutoMapper to map a Foo to a Bar, but I do **not** want the "CustomValidation" attribute to be run when the mapping happens.

This is what my mapping code looks like...

```
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember("Prop3", m => m.Ignore()));
```

Even with the MemberList.None being passed in *and* the Prop3 being specifically ignored... it still fires the CustomValidation attribute.

How can I stop it from doing that?

or alternatively...

Can I fire the CustomValidation attribute with a non-default constructor?

To put this rather strange question in context. I'm trying to unit test a Controller method that performs this mapping. The CustomValidation attribute hits the database and I want to avoid that to speed up the unit test. I do have the CustomValidation attribute set up to accept an IoC container in the constructor, which would allow me to pass in a mock and avoid the database, which would be a perfectly fine alternative solution to avoiding the validation altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Auto Mapper does not care about the validation attribute.

If you don't want the real validation to execute in your tests, I think that having the service or repository that goes to the database abstracted so that you can mock or stub it in your tests is a valid approach.

I really think that Auto Mapper is not your problem.

Comment: The custom validation attribute already accepts an IoC container as a constructor parameter so that I can unit test it with a mock repository. That works just fine when I'm unit testing the custom validation attribute in isolation.

The problem is that I'm trying to unit test a controller method which its self is performing an AutoMapper mapping from a Model to a ViewModel, and the ViewModel contains the custom validation attribute.

I can pass an IoC container into the controller, and into the custom attribute separately, but seemingly not from controller to attribute via AutoMapper.

Comment: Alright I understand now. But just so we are clear, you are talking about the validation that happens to set the value of Models tate. Is valid, right? If yes, how are you stubbing it? Pasting that code will help me help you.

Comment: *ModelState.IsValid

Comment: Exactly. The "CustomValidation" attribute is used to set ModelState.IsValid for the Bar class. The Foo class doesn't have this attribute.

When AutoMapper maps my Foo to Bar, it seems to be validating the resulting Bar using the custom attribute. I simply want to either not validate the resulting Bar, or alternatively pass an IoC container into the CustomValidation class constructor. I can't seem to do either.

Comment: @spoonraker, I don't think it makes sense for AutoMapper to try to execute any of that. May I suggest the following: Execute your test in debug mode and put a breakpoint inside the attribute. Then analyse the stacktrace. That will tell you if it's AutoMapper or something else.

Comment: I did put a break point in the custom validation class. That's how I know it's being hit. Anyway, for the particular way I was using the mapped class I didn't need the property that was giving me trouble anyway, so as a quick fix I just didn't populate it so AutoMapper skips it.

Comment: I have the same issue: source and destination classes have both a custom attribute decorating their properties and automapper seems to be instantiating these. Is there a way to prevent this?